# Bypass TypeScript constructor signature

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript class that's a declaration for a JavaScript class. The JavaScript class has a constructor with some parameters, while the TypeScript declaration is missing it (hiding on purpose).

Is there a way in TypeScript to work this around, and create a TypeScript object while still passing in parameters that are expected by the hidden JavaScript constructor?

I need it for some special test mock-ups, to work-around limitations in one library, so any hack is acceptable.

---

Here's the JavaScript class, hidden within a third-party library:

```
class InnerClass {
    constructor(param1, param2, param3) {
    }
}
```

Here's TypeScript declaration that the library exposes:

```
class InnerClass {
    // no constructor
}
```

I need to do this, somehow:

```
const a: InnerClass = new InnerClass(param1, param2, param3);
```

i.e. I need a way to create the right object, of the right TypeScript type, and pass in the correct constructor parameters, while the TypeScript declaration does not allow me to do it directly.

Is it possible to achieve in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have an escape hatch by going through `any`.

Here's one quick solution:

```
const a: InnerClass = new (InnerClass as any)(param1, param2, param3);
```

The `any` declaration will just tell Typescript - the developer can do whatever they want with this variable.

The ideal solution is to just update their declaration file to reflect it, or to clone it to your project and use that instead of their file.

Comment: That simple?! I'll be damned, how didn't I figure this one out... :)